# Prevent child window of NSWindow from moving on MacOS

Tags: macos

I add an NSWindow with button user controls as child of another NSWindow playing Video. The child window moves with its parent but can also be dragged independently. How can I prevent this, below is the code

```
   [btnwindow setMovable:false];
   [window addChildWindow:btnwindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

Thanks